# Sequelize - Nodejs - Check foreign key constraint before saving

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, async.js

This is the code for saving an "Orchard" record. The code works but I would like to understand how manage in a good way the insertion of data which contains a foreign key (in this case "cropId), this because orchardId could be an invalid value (for example it couldn't exist) so I would like to understand how handle error about foreign key constraint.

**updatev2:** I solved putting in a catch an error controller. Now the only problem I have is an "Error: Not Implemented" when I print the error

```
 OrchardService.add = function (req, res, next) {
    var orchard = req.body;

    db.Area.create({
      name: orchard.name,
      cropId: orchard.crop,
      orchard: {}
    }, {
      include: [{model: db.Orchard, as: 'orchard'}]
    })
      .then(function (area) {
        var coords = orchard.coordinates.map(function (coord) {
          coord.areaId = area.id;
          return coord;
        });
        db.AreaCoordinate.bulkCreate(coords)
          .then(function () {
            next({status: 200, status_message: 'OK', data: {orchard: area.orchardId}})
          })
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        if (err instanceof Sequelize.ForeignKeyConstraintError) {
          next({status: 501, status_message: 'Invalid Crop', error: err.message});
        } else {
          next({status: 500, status_message: 'Internal Server Error', error: err.message});
        }
        console.error(err);
      })
```

**TEST:**

```
it('Add Orchard', function (done) {
    chai.request(app)
      .post('/orchard')
      .send({
        name: 'pantano',
        crop: 1232,
        coordinates: [
          {latitude: '1', longitude: '3'},
          {latitude: '2', longitude: '4'},
          {latitude: '1', longitude: '5'}
        ]
      })
      .then(function (res) {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        expect(res).to.have.header('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');
        expect(res.body).to.have.status(200);
        expect(res.body.status_message).to.equal('OK');
        expect(res.body).to.have.property('data');
        expect(res.body.data).to.have.property('orchard');
        expect(res.body.data.orchard).to.be.an('number');

        done();
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        done(err);
      });
  });
```

**ERROR:**

```
Error: Not Implemented
    at Test.Request.callback (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:626:17)
    at node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:795:18
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:16:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

Comment: Which database is used? Maybe it's better to implement this as a DB level constraint?

Comment: Is a mysql database, this problem is handled by  DB level, it is already handled by db level...but if a cropId doesn't exist I would like to handle the error showing a message "Invalid Crop id". I thought to catch the exception but I didn't understand how...

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, there's no reason to write 'throw new Error(); doSomething()', as `throw` immediately passes the control into the next `catch`. Instead just call `next` in specific `catch` block.

Comment: I updated the question with your suggestion, now I have just a problem during unit testing

Comment: No offence, but don't you think it's a different problem deserving another question? ) It doesn't have anything to do with the question header, to say the least.